# Cypher :How to create a relationship between one node (person) and every other node (person) contained in a CSV file?

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I have a csv file containing the list of my friends'names (Person) ; and a node which represents me (Person). What i'm trying to do is to create the relationship "friend with" between me and every other friend in the csv file automatically.

I found an example which creates the relationship between a list "mark, anna, jhon, bob" and a person "x" using the command "FOREACH", but my case is more general.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be pretty easy with the [`LOAD CSV`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-load-csv.html) clause in Cypher:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///path/to/file.csv' AS line
MATCH
  (me:Person {id: {my_id}}),
  (friend:Person {id: toInt(line.id)})
WHERE {my_id} <> toInt(line.id)
CREATE (me)-[:FRIEND_WITH]->(friend)
```

You can also use `LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS` as described in the documentation.

I'm not sure exactly what your CSV file looks like, so I guessed a bit.  You might need to modify the file.  If your name is repeated over and over you might use `MERGE` for that and still use `MATCH` for the friends.

Comment: My csv file looks like this : 
id,name
1,anna
2,foo
3,keven
4,me
5,bob
(vertically with headers id and name)
i would like to do the following: 
(me) "friend with" (every friend in the csv list according to the name (exepct myself of course))

Comment: I've just updated the answer.  Hopefully that works.  You'll either need to use Cypher parameters for the `my_id` ( http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-parameters.html ) or replace it with the ID in question

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian , i will try this

Comment: Just a little issue, i hope you can help me in this last point please. My id is 141. when i replace my_id with 141 i get the error "expected a parameter named 141" . So i thought maybe i should create a node "me" with id 141 previously.i typed "CREATE  (me:Person {name: "me",id:141}) but still the same error he doesn't recognize 141 .

Comment: You should replace the entire thing, including the curly braces.  So rather than `{141}` it should just be `141`

Comment: Sorry but by writing this code below it gives me the message (no changes, no rows) ://
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///home/cloudera/neo4j/data/import/dhekra.csv' AS line
MATCH
  (me:Person {id: 141),
  (friend:Person {id: toInt(line.id)})
WHERE 141 <> toInt(line.id)
CREATE (me)-[:FRIEND_WITH]->(friend)

Comment: Is it the `id` property on your nodes which has the ID?  Are they strings or ints?